# Получить socket.id пользователя через redis-cli

Tags: node.js, socket.io, redis

Настроил связку    `redis`,    `socket.io-redis` через     `socket.io-adapter`. Запустил ноду на разных портах (3000 и 3001), все работает хорошо. На клиентскую часть эмитятся сообщения через    `publish` redis-а. Насколько я понимаю, все соединения комнаты    `io.sockets.adapter.rooms["some room"]`, помимо ноды, хранятся еще где-то в редис, так ли это?. Мониторю все через    `redis-cli monitor`, но ключи коннектов нигде не записываются, вижу только     `[0 127.0.0.1:44085] "publish" "socket.io#Ahg6iU"...`
Могу ли я получить айди сокета или список комнат через    `redis-cli` и удалить соответственно через консоль? Смотрел в сторону    `CLIENT LIST` redis-a - тоже ничего не получил.

```
var ioredis = require('socket.io-redis');
var pub = redis.createClient({port:6379, return_buffers: true});    
var sub = redis.createClient({port:6379, return_buffers: true});
var redisOptions = {
   pubClient: pub,
   subClient: sub,
   port: 6379
};
io.adapter(ioredis(redisOptions));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, разобрался, socket-коннекты не хранятся в редисе, т.к. нельзя получить их по айдишнику

```
pub.get("socket_id", function (err, reply) {
   io.to(reply.toString()).emit('test.channel', {test: 'test123123123'});
   console.log(reply.toString(), io.sockets.connected[reply.toString()]);
  //io.sockets.connected[reply.toString()].disconnect();
});
```

Чтобы сохранять это в редисе, нужно самому пропатчить сокет ио адаптер. [Ссылка на Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625556/socket-io-how-to-count-clients-in-a-room-with-socket-io-redis-adapter).